# Filter by Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in my table for dates (DateTime) and I am trying to create a WHERE clause that says, `WHERE dates BETWEEN 12-11-2012 and 12-13-2012`

A sample value of dates column = 2012-05-24 00:38:40.260

I want to say WHERE dates BETWEEN MM-DD-YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY.

I tried doing

```
WHERE dates BETWEEN ((convert(nvarchar(10), dates,110) = '2012-12-12') AND (convert(nvarchar(10), dates,110) = '2012-12-12'))
```

but doesn't seem to work. "Incorrect syntax near ="

Please help

EDIT:

Thanks for various options and description guys. Got it working with @RichardTheKiwi's options.

Comment: You have to extract dates from that Datetime field.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If your `dates` column does not contain time information, you could get away with:

```
WHERE dates BETWEEN '20121211' and '20121213'
```

However, given your `dates` column is actually datetime, you want this

```
WHERE dates >= '20121211'
  AND dates < '20121214'  -- i.e. 00:00 of the next day
```

Another option for SQL Server 2008 onwards that retains [SARGability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) (ability to use index for good performance) is:

```
WHERE CAST(dates as date) BETWEEN '20121211' and '20121213'
```

*Note: **always** use ISO-8601 format YYYYMMDD with SQL Server for unambiguous date literals.*

Comment: Note: always use ISO-8601 format YYYYMMDD throughout your LIFE, for unambiguous dates!

Answer (score 7):

```
WHERE dates BETWEEN (convert(datetime, '2012-12-12',110) AND (convert(datetime, '2012-12-12',110))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you are trying to compare Date with Nvarchar which is wrong. Should be

```
Where dates between date1 And date2
-- both date1 & date2 should be date/datetime
```

If date1,date2 strings; server will convert them to date type before filtering.