# How to filter by dates in postgres - coverting from mysql to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

**UPDATED:**  I'm trying to translate mysql code into postgres code and I want to filter between two dates in my where clause

**Original Mysql**

```
SELECT concat(month(DD1.open_date),'/', DATE_FORMAT(DD1.open_date, '%y')) AS month_year,
           venues.name AS venue_name,
           DD1.`server_name` AS SERVER_NAME,
           DD1.`server_id` AS `Server ID`,
           AVG(lr.`rating`) AS server_overall_rating,
           all_overall_rating,
           AVG(lr.`service`) AS server_service_rating,
           all_service_rating,
           avg(spend) AS server_check_avg,
           all_check_avg,
           avg(cover_avg) AS server_cover_avg,
           all_cover_avg
    FROM loyalty_visits DD1
    JOIN
      (SELECT avg(lr.rating) AS all_overall_rating,
              avg(lr.service) AS all_service_rating,
              avg(cover_avg) AS all_cover_avg,
              avg(spend) AS all_check_avg,
              open_date
       FROM loyalty_visits lv
       LEFT OUTER JOIN loyalty_ratings lr ON lr.loyalty_visit_id = lv.id
       WHERE lv.venue_id = 4046
       AND open_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 12 MONTH) AND now()
       GROUP BY lv.venue_ID,
                MONTH(open_date), year(open_date)) AS overall_cover_avg ON MONTH(overall_cover_avg.open_date) = MONTH(DD1.open_date)
    AND year(overall_cover_avg.open_date) = year(DD1.open_date)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN loyalty_member_visits lmv ON lmv.loyalty_visit_id = DD1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN loyalty_ratings lr ON lmv.loyalty_visit_id = lr.loyalty_visit_id
    JOIN venues ON venues.id = DD1.venue_id
    WHERE DD1.parent_venue_id = 4041
      AND DD1.server_id = 6991
      AND DD1.venue_id = 4046
      AND DD1.open_date BETWEEN date('2015-01-29 14:15:55') AND date('2013-09-29 10:15:55')
    GROUP BY DD1.venue_ID,
             MONTH(DD1.open_date), year(DD1.open_date)
    ORDER BY DD1.open_date LIMIT 6
```

**Postgres**
NOTE:  I know my projection isn't all there compared to the original mysql, it's because I'm actually try to understand subquerying (which I have no idea how it's working) and also trying to learn where some of the select statements are coming from in the mysql version so I can adequately convert to Postgres.

**ALSO**

loyalty_visits as DD1 in Mysql was changed to members_visits as mv in Postgres and loyalty_ratings as lr was changed to to just ratings as r in Postgres.  The rest should still be the same.

```
SELECT mv.check_number,
mv.open_date,
mv.code,
mv.cover_avg,
reservation_loyalty_user_id,
v.restaurant_id,
table_name,
terminal_id
FROM member_visits as mv
FROM member_visits as mv
JOIN
      (SELECT avg(lr.rating) AS all_overall_rating,
              avg(lr.service) AS all_service_rating,
              avg(cover_avg) AS all_cover_avg,
              avg(spend) AS all_check_avg,
              open_date
       FROM loyalty_visits lv
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings lr ON lr.loyalty_visit_id = lv.id
       WHERE lv.venue_id = 4046
         AND open_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 3 MONTH) AND now()
       GROUP BY lv.venue_ID,
                   MONTH(open_date), year(open_date)) AS overall_cover_avg  ON     MONTH(overall_cover_avg.open_date) = MONTH(DD1.open_date)
    AND year(overall_cover_avg.open_date) = year(DD1.open_date)
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
    ON mv.loyalty_visit_id = r.loyalty_visit_id
JOIN venues v
    ON v.id = mv.venue_id
WHERE mv.parent_venue_id = 4041
AND mv.server_id = 6991
AND mv.venue_id = 4046
AND mv.open_date BETWEEN date_trunc('2015/01/20', day) AND date_trunc('2013/09/29', day)
GROUP BY mv.venue_ID,
            MONTH(mv.open_date), YEAR(mv.open_date)
ORDER BY mv.open_date
limit 10
```

I'm getting two errors:

1)  In this line

`AND open_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 12 MONTH) AND now()`,

Is it possible there is no data between now and 12 months?  I'm not sure how to debug this.

2) I also get an error that says
`invalid input syntax for integer: "2015-01-2013 14:15:55"`

I've seen this post [Filter by Dates in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869640/filter-by-dates-in-sql) but I'm not sure I like the solution and it's a SQL solution.  Then I tried playing with the `date_trunc` but I"m not sure that's correct either.

Anything I should be using?

Comment: '2015-01-2013 14:15:55' is a valid datetime ?

Comment: it's a result that get in the open_date column so I assumed so?

Comment: can you please give the data structure of you `member_visits` table ?

Comment: Ah...revealing...it says BigInt...

Comment: I think I can just use a date( ) that'll convert the int into a date?

Comment: I just tried to wrap that into a date( ) and I get this following error ==> `ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2015-01-2013 14:15:55"
  Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.`

Comment: listen please, do you really think that `2015-01-2013` is a valid date ?

Comment: And to answer you: Yes you can use for example (if really necessary): [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: No luck and yes, I changed `2015-01-2013` to `2015-01-20`.  Nothing seems to be working.  I'll update the date in the original post.

Comment: Postgresql doesn't handle `interval 1 month` the right way is `interval '1 month'` see it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Another thing you are mixing mysql functions on your postgresql query, it will not work.

Comment: A date expression using BETWEEN requires the earlier date to come first.

Comment: It looks like an invalid query (also in MySQL!), the GROUP BY and ORDER BY looks suspicious: GROUP BY mv.venue_ID,
            MONTH(mv.open_date), YEAR(mv.open_date)
ORDER BY mv.open_date. Could you show us the complete query? The SELECT to start with, is missing.

Comment: @FrankHeikens yea, totally, I can send the you Select statement.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, you are correct, I"m trying to convert this into Postgres from mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) `date_sub()` function in Postgres. Just subtract the interval from the timestamp (or date). Your interval literal is wrong as well.

The SQL standard requires the value to be put in single quotes e.g. `interval '12' month` or `interval '5' minute`. Postgres also allows a syntax where the value and the unit are in single quotes `interval '1 month'`

```
AND open_date BETWEEN now() - interval '12' MONTH AND now()
```

Your `date_trunc` usage [is also wrong](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). The string literal  `'2015/01/20'` will only be converted to a date when your current date format matches this. In general it is **much** better to use ANSI date literals to make sure your SQL runs in every environment regardless of the date format setting:

```
date_trunc('day', DATE '2015-01-20')
```

Postgres also (always) accepts a string literal that uses an ISO format so `'2015-01-20'` is working the same way as `DATE '2015-01-20'` in Postgres

There is also no `date()` function in Postgres. I recommend to use ANSI date and timestamp literals. So instead of `date('2015-01-29 14:15:55')` use `timestamp '2015-01-29 14:15:55'` which adheres to the SQL standard. If you don't want to an ISO date format, you should use the `to_date()` or `to_timestamp()` [functions with an appropriate format mask](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

There is also no `date_format` function in Postgres. Use `to_char()`. Again this [is documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

There is also no `year()` or `month()` function in Postgres. Use the SQL standard: `extract(year from open_date)` or `extract(month from open_date)` or the Postgres specific `date_part()` function. This is also [documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)