# In sql, how to filter records in two joined tables

Tags: sql-server

I output invoices that are made up of info in two separate data tables linked by a unique ID #. I need to update the service provided in a group of invoices (service info contained in table_B) for only a certain date period (date info contained in table_A).

Here's the two tables I am joining

Table_A

```
ID------|Name-----------------|Date----------|Total--------|

1-------|--ABC Company--------|--1/1/17------|--$50--------|

2-------|--John Smith---------|--3/1/17------|--$240-------|

3-------|--Mary Jones---------|--2/1/16------|--$320-------|

1-------|--ABC Company--------|--8/1/16------|--$500-------|
```

Table_B

```
Table_ID (= ID Table_A)----|-Service-----------|Unit Price--|Qty------| 


1--------------------------|--Service A--------|--$50.00----|--10-----|
                                         --
2--------------------------|--Service B--------|--$20.00----|--12-----|
                                         --
3--------------------------|--Service B--------|--$20.00----|--16-----|
                                         --
1--------------------------|--Service A--------|--$50.00----|--10-----|
```

I am able to join the two tables using:

Select * from Table_B b inner join Table_A a on b.Table_ID = a.ID

which results in following:

Results

```
Table_ID-|-Service-----|-Unit Price-|-Qty-|-ID--|-Name-----|-Date----|Total--|

1--------|-Service A-  |$50.00------|-10--|-1---|-ABC Co.--|-1/1/17--|$500--|

2--------|-Service B-  |$20.00------|-12--|-2---|-John S.--|-3/1/17--|$240--|

3--------|-Service B-  |$20.00------|-16--|-3---|-Mary J.--|-2/1/16--|$320--|

1--------|-Service A-  |&50.00------|-10--|-1---|-ABC Co.--|-8/1/16--|$500--|
```

Now, I want only rows that are for dates greater 12/31/16. However, when I add a where clause for the date (see below) my results don't change.

```
Select * from Table_B b inner join Table_A a on b.Table_ID = a.ID where date > 12/31/16
```

I would expect just two rows for services on 1/1/17 and 3/1/17. How can I filter for just rows with a particular date value in this newly joined table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter by Dates in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869640/filter-by-dates-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date is contained in a column intended for storing dates, and not string, try making sure that the date you're passing in really is being interpreted as a date:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_b b 
  INNER JOIN 
  table_a a 
    on b.Table_ID = a.ID 
WHERE 
  a.date > CONVERT(datetime , '20161231' , 112 )
```

I suspect that SQLSERVER is interpreting your date `12/31/16` as "twelve divided by thirty one divided by sixteen" - a floating point number approximately 0.0241935

The way dates are handled, internally, they are convertable to floating point numbers representing the number (and fraction of) days since a certain point in time, I believe 1 Jan 1900. Hence your 0.024 floating point number will represent a date about 35 minutes past midnight on 01 jan 1900.. and that's why your results aren't filtering, because all the dates satisfy the where clause (theyre all later than 01-01-1900 00:35)!

Comment: @Turtle, 112 is datetime format, for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Indeed, one of the things I've always thought SQLServer could have done better (like Oracle did). CONVERT accepts numeric parameters for a bunch of different pre-programmed date formats.. 112 is yyyymmdd, 101 is mm/dd/yy etc. There's no logic, so you have to rely on documentation.. Oracle has a to_date function that parses as given (e.g. you can pass in 'yyyy.dd.mm') - to get this functionality in sqlserver you need to use .net extensions. If your string dates aren't in one of the pre-programmed formats you normally have to use string concat/chop to rearrrange the string before CONVERT()ing it

Answer (score 0):

Please test below script, it may give you expected output.

```
Select * 
from Table_B b 
    inner join Table_A a 
        on b.Table_ID = a.ID 
        and date > convert(date , '20161231' , 112 )
```

Comment: Avoid use of implicit date conversions. Your query relies on SQLServer guessing that the string '12/31/16' represents a date in american format. There's no guarantee that this would work on another server elsewhere in the world that has a different date format setting, especially if the date is '5/10/16' -> is that 10th of may, or 5th of oct? Better to be precise: give your date in a known format, and use convert to specify the format e.g CONVERT(datetime, 'yyyymmdd', 112)

Comment: Edited, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What result are you getting with your current implementation, because I don't see any issue with your current query

Comment: I needed to cvt the date. Using the following query worked: SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_b b 
  INNER JOIN 
  table_a a 
    on b.Table_ID = a.ID 
WHERE 
  a.date > CONVERT(datetime , '20161231' , 112 )

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * 
from Table_B b 
inner join Table_A a 
  on b.Table_ID = a.ID 
  where date > '12/31/16'
```

Can you try to use the quotes with your date.

Or best way is to use

```
Select * 
from Table_B b 
inner join Table_A a 
  on b.Table_ID = a.ID 
  where Date BETWEEN '12/31/2016' and '1/1/2018'
```

Comment: Do not rely on implicit string->date conversions, as per my comment to PawelCz