# SQL select between two dates and time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select all data from yesterday of 6:59 PM up to 7:00 PM of today everyday.

Data to be selected is a `datetime` field.
The date is not constant as I am going to generate it everyday with this query.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008. Here is a sample test data.

[image: Sample DateTimeField Data]

Could you give me an idea how am i going to do it

```
SELECT transaction
FROM test_tbl
WHERE ...
```

Comment: You can make use of `BETWEEN` or `Operators` such as '>,=,<'. Give it a try.[Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869640/filter-by-dates-in-sql)

Comment: Do you want to select all data between 6:59PM and 7:00PM? Or Do you want to select all data from 6:59PM and 7:00PM Yesterday and then use this data (key?) to select corresponding rows Today?

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski date is not constant as I am going to generate it everyday with this query

Comment: Then I believe @DhruvJoshi has answer to your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the column containing the date time field in WHERE clause, if your column is `transactionDatTim` then query is like below:

```
DECLARE @tempDate DATE -- note that this date and not DateTime
DECLARE @tempStartDateTime DATETIME, @tempEndDateTime DATETIME
SET @tempDate = GETDATE()
SET @tempEndDateTime = DATEADD(hh,19,CAST(@tempDate AS datetime))
SET @tempStartDateTime  = DATEADD(mi,-1,DATEADD(d,-1,@tempEndDateTime))


--the query
SELECT transaction
FROM test_tbl
WHERE transactionDatTim BETWEEN @tempStartDateTime  AND @tempEndDateTime
```

shorter version w/o temp variables will be

```
--the query
SELECT transaction
FROM test_tbl
WHERE transactionDatTim BETWEEN 
   DATEADD(mi,-((24-19)*60+1),CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS datetime))  
    AND 
   DATEADD(hh,19,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS datetime))
```

Comment: i believe this is correct but i dont know why there is no output when i apply it to my query. trying again, will give you update. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this and see

```
select transaction from test_tb1 where transaction between '2017-05-02 18:59:00' and '2017-05-03 19:00:00';
```

Comment: this is actually what i did before but the thing is that the date is not constant

Answer (score 0):

You can use "between" clause to find the records that lie between the two end dates (inclusive) :

TRY:

```
SELECT transaction
FROM test_tbl

where datetime between 
cast(convert(varchar, DATEADD(dd,-1, GETDATE()), 101)+' 6:59 PM' as datetime) --to get yesterday's date and time at 6:59 *hardcoded*
and 
cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)+' 7:00 PM' as datetime) --to get current date at 7pm
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT created_at, id FROM `tbl_invoice_item` WHERE date(created_at)
>   between date('2018-11-26') AND date('2018-11-28') AND time(created_at)
>   BETWEEN '12:00' AND '12:40'