# Weird query result when filtering dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a 40 thousand rows .csv file of football matches with dates on each game. I have formatted the dates column in 'YY-MM-DD' format with lubridate in R, so every row is like that and checked if it's in Date class, which it is.

After that I just saved the .csv file (with fwrite function in data.table) and  added it to my database which is in sqlite3.

When I run this query:

```
-- The important part is the WHERE clause
SELECT dates, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score, city, country FROM History_games
WHERE dates < '19300713'
```

To filter and get games before the 13th of July of 1930. The query runs but I get matches up to: 1930-12-07 (which is the 7th of December 1930).
If I use 19301307 (which would be wrong) the same result comes back.

I did the same filter in R with lubridate and in Python with pandas and there was no problem. My last row is 1930-07-06 (July the 6th of 1930), which is the correct date.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong with the query? I have tried it in db browser sqlite3 and datagrip and both of them throw the same result.

Thanks

Comment: If you formatted the dates with the format 'YY-MM-DD' and you compare them with a date formatted with 'YYYYMMDD' why do you expect to get correct results?

Comment: Based on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869640/filter-by-dates-in-sql. I thought that putting it YYMMDD in the query will work even though my data has dashes. I will try the answer above from that post

Comment: That post is about SQL Server, not SQLite. My suggestion is to use only the format YYYY-MM-DD with SQLite